# Rails helpers in controller and creating model object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4

Please look at the image given in the link .
http://i.cubeupload.com/YZtQkP.jpg

1.what does before_action helper means in this controller .? 
2.what do we call this "set_product" after before_action .? 
3.what does only and the action names mean here .? 
4. Inside the index action there is a command

```
Product.all
```

and Product is a model name that i know. But when executed in browser by default it looks the index action . does this code "product.all" creates a object or is that the command

```
product.new
```

in the new action creates the object .

because i doing a project on rails without learning ruby . so please give me a solution .

Comment: give solution for what?

Comment: "because i doing a project on rails without learning ruby" Solution: learn Ruby!

Comment: before_action .. as the name implies what it does . but what do we call it "set_product" and what's its purpose . because i didn't learnt ruby it hard for me to understand it. give me way to understand the above 4 questions .. @SaidKaldybaev

Comment: `What does before_action helper means in this controller` - have you at least tried googling it?

Comment: before_action means that it's happening before the action.
So before the show action it called a controller method called "set_product". Only means it does it only before those actions are called so now on the new or index action.

I'd suggest heading to [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/)

Comment: @Baloo .. yeah now i understand it. thank you ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.all is a method used on a model (in this case Product) that calls all of the instances of that model.

set_product is an method that is used before the show, edit, update and destroy methods. It sets the product that you want to use for those actions.

I think you would really benefit from learning ruby while learning rails. I would recommend Michael Hartl's excellent Rails Tutorial which is available, for free, on his site.